# Can I tell DeleteCases not to delete function arguments?

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

Given `list = {1, 2, f[3, 4], {5, {6, g[7, h[8, 9]]}}, {f[10], 11}};`

I want to get
`{f[3, 4], {{g[7, h[8, 9]]}}, {f[10]}}`

just delete a single integer and need to keep the structure, use `DeleteCases` but get this result

```
DeleteCases[list, _Integer, All, Heads -> False]
```

> {f[], {{g[h[]]}}, {f[]}}

Am I using it wrong, should I use a more suitable function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
list /. {expr : (f | g | h)[__] :> expr, _Integer -> Nothing}
(* {f[3, 4], {{g[7, h[8, 9]]}}, {f[10]}} *)
```

Comment: A slight variation: `list/.{_Integer:>Nothing,x:_f | _g | _h :> x}` (and +1, of course)

Answer (score 11):

You could use `DeleteCases` on each `List`:

```
MapAt[DeleteCases[_Integer], list, Drop[Position[list, List], 0, -1]]
```

> ```
> {f[3, 4], {{g[7, h[8, 9]]}}, {f[10]}}
> ```

Answer (score 10):

I might think of this as transforming each list into a special type of list that automatically deletes any non-atomic elements given to it.

```
list /. List -> Function[Null, Select[{##}, Not@*AtomQ]]
```

I generalized this to atoms instead of just integers, because that's what I "read between the lines" of your question. But of course you could stick with integers.

```
list /. List -> Function[Null, Select[{##}, Not@*IntegerQ]]
```

or

```
list /. List -> Function[Null, DeleteCases[{##}, _Integer]]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
list //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[__Integer, keep : (_@__) ..]} :> {keep}
```

> ```
> {f[3, 4], {{g[7, h[8, 9]]}}, {f[10]}}
> ```

And a variation on @xzczd's method:

```
list /. {keep : Except[List]@__ :> keep, _Integer -> Nothing}
```

> ```
> {f[3, 4], {{g[7, h[8, 9]]}}, {f[10]}}
> ```

Comment: Just `keep___` works for the first (and three underscores/dots are needed if it's possible to empty a list)

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this using `SubsetReplace`, Internal-CopyListStructure  and `ReplaceAll`:

```
Internal`CopyListStructure[list, 
SubsetReplace[Flatten@list, {_Integer} -> s]] /. s -> Nothing

(*{f[3, 4], {{g[7, h[8, 9]]}}, {f[10]}}*)
```

Or the equivalent form:

```
F = Activate@
Internal`CopyListStructure[#, 
SubsetReplace[Flatten@#, {_Integer} -> Inactive[Nothing]]] &;

F@list

(*{f[3, 4], {{g[7, h[8, 9]]}}, {f[10]}}*)
```

A generalization of @xzczd's answer is to find the heads of expressions that we don't want to remove using `Cases` as follows:

```
patt = Alternatives @@ Blank /@ Union@Cases[#, 
       s : Except[_List | _Integer] :> Head[s], {0, ∞}] &@list

(*_f | _g | _h*)

list /. {_Integer :> Nothing, s : patt :> s}

(*{f[3, 4], {{g[7, h[8, 9]]}}, {f[10]}}*)
```

Another way, using `Cases` and `DeleteCases`:

```
exc = Cases[#, s : Except[_List | _Integer] :> s, {0, ∞}] &;

DeleteCases[#, Alternatives @@ Complement[Flatten@#, exc@#], Depth@#] &@list

(*{f[3, 4], {{g[7, h[8, 9]]}}, {f[10]}}*)
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell if this is clever or just silly, but it's a variation on the theme:

```
In[22]:= noIntegers[bef___, __Integer, aft___] := noIntegers[bef, aft];
In[23]:= list /. List -> noIntegers /. noIntegers -> List

Out[23]= {f[3, 4], {{g[7, h[8, 9]]}}, {f[10]}}
```